# How to efficiently draw lots of objects using Three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am new to WebGL and Three.js. I am trying to visualize a large grid of circles changing colors at once.

As I increase the number of instances, it gets noticeably slower, where it takes seconds to update. What are some suggestions for improving my code? Can I update 4000 circles at once?

Here is my existing implementation:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first Three.js app</title>
        <style></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="./three.js"></script>
        <script>
        var ROWS = 40
        var COLS = 100
        var SEGMENTS = 10;

        var windowWidth = window.innerWidth, windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var group, text, plane;

        function init() {
            // create and append container/canvas
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            // create camera    
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, windowWidth / windowHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
            // set position of camera
            camera.position.z = 500;
            camera.position.x = windowWidth/2
            camera.position.y = windowHeight/2

            // Create a scene
            scene = new THREE.Scene();


            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor( 0xf0f0f0 );
            renderer.setSize( windowWidth, windowHeight );
            renderer.sortElements = false;
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
        }

        function addCircle(color, x, y, z, s , radius) {    
            var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(radius, SEGMENTS, SEGMENTS)
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: color, overdraw: true } );

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            mesh.position.set( x, y, z );
            mesh.scale.set( s, s, s );
            scene.add( mesh );
        }

        function toHex(d) {
            var valueStr = d.toString(16); 
            valueStr = valueStr.length < 2 ? "0"+valueStr : valueStr; 
            var fillColor = "0x00" + valueStr + "00"; 
            return parseInt(fillColor);
        }

        function drawData(data) {
            var rows = data.length;
            var cols = data[0].length;

            distanceBetweenCircles = Math.min(windowWidth/(cols), windowHeight/(rows));
            var radius = distanceBetweenCircles/2.0

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
                    var color = toHex(data[i][j])
                    var x = distanceBetweenCircles*j - radius
                    var y = distanceBetweenCircles*i - radius
                    addCircle( color, x, y, 0, 1 , radius-3);
                }
            }
        }

        function newData(){
            var newData = []
            for (var i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
                var row = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < COLS; j ++) {
                    row.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*255));
                }
                newData.push(row);
            }
            return newData;
        }

        function onDocumentMouseDown ( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();

            // Update circles 
            var randomData = newData()
            drawData(randomData);
        }

        var render = function() {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        init(); 
        render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a CircleGeometry object to a scene requires the circle to be **drawn**. Adding an image/texture of a circle to a scene requires the circle to be **printed**, so to speak.

Multiply that by 4000 and the drawing becomes quite expensive.

Answer (score 0):

It would be faster to maintain an array of the meshes and update their properties, rather than creating a new set of geometries, materials and meshes every mouse click.

Answer (score -1):

Memory management is extremely important in software design. There is a cost to every variable you introduce, especially those who's instantiation invokes a cascade of allocations behind some API call. This is the down side of using layerings like THREE which hide complexity but also hide ramifications of using their calls. Short of avoiding THREE and doing all the WebGL plumbing yourself (which is always a good first step before ignoring the plumbing and just using a shim like THREE), do some homework to identify what is getting created as you make calls to any API, like THREE.  Rip out of inner loops variable creation for objects which should be reused across calls.  To your question, yes you can easily update 4000 circles across each animation event loop time slice once your architecture is carefully thought through especially if you use shaders to craft your objects and avoid such computation back in the CPU

For pure speed I suggest you learn graphics by writing OpenGL/WebGL by hand instead of the higher level abstraction library Three.js ... the price of ease of use too often is higher computational load of unnecessary logic which can be cut out if written by hand

Here is a WebGL toy I built which has no Three.js ... it does real-time updates to geometry of 10's of thousands of objects as well as rendering audio using Web Audio API
https://github.com/scottstensland/webgl-3d-animation